# cannot open git Extensions?

Tags: git, git-extensions

I have downloaded Git Extensions from this link : http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8f594baa-e44e-4114-8381-e175ace0fe97 
. It is downloaded successfully But the problem is I can not Open it !!

By the way , I am using windows 7 64- Operating system and I have repair it but still the same !! Also, I have UnInstall  it  and re- Install it but still the same problem !!

I went to Event Viewer and Get this Error :

```
Faulting application name: GitExtensions.exe, version: 2.47.3.0, time stamp: 0x528680a0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1677
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000940d
Faulting process id: 0x11c4
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf6a9af93c7733
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\GitExtensions\GitExtensions.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 36f19fbb-d68e-11e3-ad79-782bcba8c7b0
```

Comment: try to download it from its site and try again: https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/

Comment: Thanks @jepessen  But it is Not Working as well same problem !! :(

Comment: Time to contact MicroSoft support ... but I don't expect them to be able to help you.

Comment: if you have a `C:\Users\[youruser]\AppData\Local\GitExtensions\*` folder delete it before re-try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try downgrading your version of Git Extensions. If that doesn't work, take a look at some of these links. They contain some solutions that may work for you.

https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/1530

https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/2185

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the files from Appdata/Local/GitExtensions and Appdata/Roaming/GitExtensions. You have to set up your profil again, but atleast it will work again. After the setup you can save theese file for a later crash, so you can simply load it back.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue on Windows 10. I did the following to resolve the issue:

- `cd %AppData%`
- Delete (or rename) the folder `GitExtensions`